# Cassandra 1.2 How to export large CF to csv file

Tags: java, csv, cassandra, datastax

I have large CF I need to export. What can I do? COPY can't help, shows "Request did not complete within rpc_timeout." There is on idea to make a SELECT with WHERE clause and use TimeUUID, but how I can get UUID from the first record(Java Code will be perfect)? And than what would be CQL statement for SELECT(SELECT * FROM "HISTORY_ENTITY" WHERE UUID >= uuidofthefirstrow LIMIT 1000;).

Comment: for avoiding rpc_timeout error you can increase the read_request_timeout_in_ms in cassandra.yaml file.

Comment: As I read about this problem it didn't help

Comment: Depending on your RF you can try the SSTable to JSON utility. What are you trying to achieve with a giant CSV?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it worked for me

cassandra-cli -h yourhost -p 9160 --file command.txt > listing.txt

In your file (this case, command.txt), you put :

```
use keyspaceName;
list requests limit 1000000000;
```

This copy the rows and all its contents on listing.txt